# Why aren't the Samsung Series 7 fn keys able to change screen brightness?

Tags: windows-7

Samsung Series 7 laptops use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to increase and decrease display brightness.  When I press the those keys, an indicator appears on screen but no change is made to the brightness.  Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fn keys are handled by the Samsung dmhkcore.exe process ( C:\Program Files (x86)\Samsung\Easy Settings\dmhkcore.exe ).  If you are logged in as a limited user, the <kbd>Fn</kbd> combinations with <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> will not work.

Terminate the process and rerun it as administrator.

Edit:  I have found that opening the exe in a hex editor and searching for `asInvoker` (near the end of the file) and changing it to `requireAdministrator` will get the UAC prompt to appear at startup (so terminating it and restarting it is no longer necessary).